# How to scale a logo overtop of a responsive slider

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have a slider that is scaling based on the browser width.
I have added a logo **ontop** of this slider (can't be part of image).

**Problem:** I'm not sure how to get the logo to scale so it's relatively in the same position and same size based on the slider.

http://www.nsy4mh.com/

New to responsive, so looking at getting the best way to accomplish this so I can use it on other sites in the future. I'd prefer to not have to create 6-8 media queries, so wondering if there's any alternatives.

```
#logo {
  left: 125px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: Try to use @media in css or use bootstrap classes  to scale.

Comment: 1) Please do not link to a live site, as per the FAQ. 2) Is your slider a HTML5 input+range?

Comment: Try defining the `left`, `top` & `width` attributes on the `#logo` as percentages instead of pixels.

Comment: @ckuijjer I feel like a bozo! changing all the attributes to percentages seemed to work just fine. It also seems to work for the text as well! Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything you know of that would do the same thing for the font that's inside the slider?